# How to perform gradient effect in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to perform a gradient effect that shines from bottom of the layout as appear in the following picture. Notice that it is not a regular  tag with start colour and end colour because I tried those but I haven't reach to the required solution. Also I don't want to set the background with a picture because I’m concern of quality issues. Please help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a radial gradient?

Comment: @J.Romero  
Can I use a radial gradient to make the colour shines from the bottom?

Comment: Yes and no. yes you can, "shine" is just a color but no you can't get the exact effect you want via gradient drawable (see the duplicate recommendation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using XML drawables in Android. I recommend using images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I will do this should I worry about quality issues on different phone screens?

Comment: @MansourFahad, Good question. Android has different folders for (amongst other things) different resolutions. If you put different resolutions into the correct folders, you won't have an issue. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources